# How can I run puppeteer 24/7 on my local machine

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I have been having problems running puppeteer scripts 24/7 on my local machine because whenever I close the display, it stops running. I know that it is more convenient to run such long processes on platforms such as heroku, but heroku has restrictions that stop my code from running.

If anyone has a solution, please let me know.

Comment: It would be much better to run your script on a server - it doesn't have to be Heroku, but some kind of server which does not have the restrictions which stop your code from running.

Comment: Sounds like a power settings issue.